# Boto - AWS SNS how to extract topic's ARN number

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sns

When creating a AWS SNS topic:

```
a = conn.create_topic(topicname)
```

or getting the topic already created:

```
a = conn.get_all_topics()
```

the result is:

```
{u'CreateTopicResponse': {u'ResponseMetadata': {u'RequestId': u'42b46710-degf-52e6-7d86-2ahc8e1c738c'}, u'CreateTopicResult': {u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:467741034465:exampletopic'}}}
```

The question is how do you get topic's ARN as string: `arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:467741034465:exampletopic` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new topic, boto returns a Python dictionary with the data you describe above.  To get the topic ARN as a string, simply reference that key in the dictionary like this:

```
a = conn.create_topic(topicname)
a_arn = a['CreateTopicResponse']['CreateTopicResult']['TopicArn']
```

it's kind of clunky but it works.

The `list_topics` call returns a different structure, basically like this:

```
{u'ListTopicsResponse':
  {u'ListTopicsResult':
    {u'NextToken': None,
     u'Topics': [
      {u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:467741034465:exampletopic'},
      {u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:467741034465:footopic'}
     ]
    },
  u'ResponseMetadata': {u'RequestId': u'aef821f6-d595-55e1-af14-6d3a8064536a'}}}
```

In this case, if you wanted to get the ARN of the first topic you would use:

```
a = conn.list_topics()
a_arn = a['ListTopicsResponse']['ListTopicsResult']['Topics'][0]['TopicArn']
```

Comment: One thing to note here is that calling `create_topic` over and over is an idempotent action. If the topic already exists for the account, a new one will _not_ be created. Calling `create_topic` seems like the best method of retrieving a topic's ARN ID.

Answer (score 7):

```
import boto

def get_account_id():
    # suggested by https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boto-users/QhASXlNBm40
    return boto.connect_iam().get_user().arn.split(':')[4]

def topic_arn_from_name(self, region, name):
    return ":".join(["arn", "aws", "sns", region, get_account_id(), name])
```

Comment: This likely won't work if you want to publish across accounts, right?