# Boto (Python): Checking SQS -> SNS subscription

Tags: python, boto, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have an SNS arn and an SQS arn. I would like to check if there is a subscription between the two. The only way I can do this right now is to brute force the list of subscription like this:

```
    result =  self.connection.get_all_subscriptions_by_topic(sns_arn)
    if (result and result['ListSubscriptionsByTopicResponse'] 
        and result['ListSubscriptionsByTopicResponse']
        and result['ListSubscriptionsByTopicResponse']['ListSubscriptionsByTopicResult']):
        subscriptions = result['ListSubscriptionsByTopicResponse']['ListSubscriptionsByTopicResult']['Subscriptions']
        for subscription in subscriptions:
            if (subscription['Protocol'] == type and subscription['Endpoint'] == sqs_arn and subscription['SubscriptionArn']):
                return subscription['SubscriptionArn']
    return None
```

Can I do better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656286/boto-aws-sns-how-to-extract-topics-arn-number may give you ideas.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I am trying to avoid.